# $ sudo fdisk -l : Why does not it display the file system type?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, filesystem, ntfs, fdisk

I am using the dual boot system, Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.

Then, many articles says,

`$ sudo fdisk -l`

the command line tells what file system each /dev/sda uses.

But my ouput displays "Microsoft basic data" in Type column on a /dev/sda that is Windows 10 partition, my expecting answer is NTFS though.

Is there any option of "fdisk" command or other command line to provide me what I want as the output.

Thank you for reading.
I wish I could get any advice.

Comment: What's `fdisk --version` return?

Comment: Hello! fdisk --version says: fdisk from util-linux 2.34
Is the problem this version 2.34?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1262566/edit) your question and add the output of both `fdisk -l` and `parted -l`.  I am thinking that `fdisk` might have an issue with GPT formatted disks.

Comment: For Terrance, thank you for commenting!   As I tried, "parted -l" tells me the /dev/sda of Windows10 is using ntfs in the File system column. I understand "parted -l" is the fit for my purpose. But I still want to know why "fdisk -l" does not output as many articles.

Comment: There is still a probability that fdisk doesn't fully understand GPT partitions.  I gave up using fdisk at my job because I work around servers that are formatted in GPT and there are much better tools for manipulating those drives with.  parted being one of the best in my opinion.

Comment: For Terrance, Hello! As you saying, I've decided to use the alternative, whenever I find any other way or tools. Even if I did not get same output as any article or textbook instruction, I would go forward after some research. Thank you for your supports!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df -Th
```

Note: This only shown filesystem which are mounted.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for suggestion! I tried "df -Th" after mounting the /dev/sda of Windows10.  "df -Th" says the /dev/sda type is "fuseblk", the"/" is "ext4" as it is expected though.  The reason I post this question is to tell how to check which /dev/sda is the Windows 10 partition for my friend to want to mount it correctly. so I want to know the way to confirm the /dev/sda is Windows 10's one before mounting.

Comment: Ok. Just for information, in linux you will often see ntfs reported as fuseblk: https://it.toolbox.com/question/ntfs-formatted-hard-drive-always-mounts-with-the-file-system-fuseblk-071914

Comment: As there could be many NTFS partitions, mounting and checking for Windows folder may be the only way.

Comment: Maybe I was a bit nervous. If any partition that is not one I really want is mounted, it is not a big problem and which tells me, on the contrary, it is not what I want with checking inside contents as you saying. There is no need to operate with the perfect way from the beginning. I will continue to learn with more relaxed feeling. Thank you for your supports and providing information!